# Position SKSpriteNode at 0,0?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've read that 0,0 is at the bottom left corner in Sprite Kit but when I position a sprite at that location nothing shows up on screen.

```
let squareSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
squareSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)                                  // bottom left corner of square
squareSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
addChild(squareSprite)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with different iOS device resolutions in SpriteKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205882/dealing-with-different-ios-device-resolutions-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because your view size, and your scene size have different dimensions. I guess you are using default game project template where the scene is loaded from .sks file (scene size in that case is 1024x768). If scene has different size than a view even if the sprite is added, it might not be visible because it can be off-screen. You can test this by adding a sprite at other position (eg. x=300,y=300). One thing you can do is to simply change scene's size (inside view controller) like this: `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` Also the important thing here is scene's [scale mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/scaleMode) (from the docs):

> After a scene is rendered, its contents are copied into the presenting
>   view. If the view and the scene are the same size, then the content
>   can be directly copied into the view. If the two differ, then the
>   scene is scaled to fit in the view. The scaleMode property determines
>   how the content is scaled.

On top of this, I would suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30713792/3402095) about how to initialize your scene in view controller and there is also debate about [viewDidLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) vs [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) methods.

Unrelated to your problem, but you might find useful to know that changing anchor point will not affect on physics body of a node. It's a [purely visual property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22095389/3402095).

Hope this helps.