# How to center a SKPhysicsBody(texture: size:) in a point other than the SKSpriteNode anchor point

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

The SKSpriteNode anchor point is set to (0.5, 0).

How can you create a physics body with `SKPhysicsBody(texture: size:)` centered at (0.5,0.5), without changing the (0.5, 0) anchor point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [+ bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:) or 
[+ bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithCircleOfRadius:center:), like this:

```
 let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
 sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))
 sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

 sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size, center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: sprite.size.height/2.0))
 sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false // just added for easier debugging
 addChild(sprite)
```

Center parameter represents the origin of the square/circle in the owning node’s coordinate system.

Comment: I need to use SKPhysicsBody(texture: size:) to get a body with the shape of the texture but with a different size.

Comment: @crvo84 Ah, okay...So, what is the reason of changing node's anchor point ? Can't you just leave it as (0.5,0.5) and change node's position accordingly ?

Comment: One useful post about anchorPoint & physicsBody. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22095999/3402095

Comment: Inside the scene, I need to rotate the sprite around the anchor point at (0.5, 0). It would be great if there is a way to change the body center so I would not need to change all my code accordingly. thanks!