# Expand SKSpritenode in one direction, in Xcode SpriteKit, using Swift

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to make an `SKSpritenode` expand only in one direction, in this case only upwards.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var rightlegs = SKSpriteNode()
    rightlegs.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 50)
    rightlegs.color = SKColor.yellowColor()
    rightlegs.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2 + 20, self.frame.height / 2 - 40)
    self.addChild(rightlegs)


}

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
```

So.. When i press the screen I want the height to expand; however, not from both direction. How do I solve this problem? Thank for your time:)

Comment: Just an idea here. Maybe you could try to update the size of your node while also changing its position by sizeIncrease/2. For example, to expand your node 20px to the top : rightlegs.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 70); rightlegs.position = CGPointMake(rightlegs.position.width, rightlegs.position + 10).

Comment: Ooh maybe that could work thank you!, i will have to try it out. Can I change the size as a SKAction?@Heyfara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing the [anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/anchorPoint) property of the sprite to `CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.0)` (this will bottom-align sprite's texture)  and scaling the sprite's height using [yScale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/yScale) property, like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let rightlegs = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 50))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        rightlegs.anchorPoint.y = 0.0

        rightlegs.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2 + 20, self.frame.height / 2 - 40)
        self.addChild(rightlegs)    
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        //Without animation
        rightlegs.yScale += 0.2
    }
}
```

Or you can make it animated using some of the SKAction scaling methods:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

   //With animation

   rightlegs.runAction(SKAction.scaleYTo(rightlegs.yScale + 0.2, duration: 0.2))
}
```

About `anchorPoint` from docs:

> Defines the point in the sprite that corresponds to the node’s
>   position.
>
> You specify the value for this property in the unit coordinate space.
>   The default value is (0.5,0.5), which means that the sprite is
>   centered on its position.

Basically what `anchorPoint` does is that it defines how texture will be drawn relative to node's position and affects on rotation and scaling of a node...

A good explanation about how anchor point works and what it does can be found in Apple's [Working with Sprites](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW36) section of documentation.

Comment: A good explanation of `anchorPoint` property can be found [here](http://www.thinkingswiftly.com/anchorpoint-skspritenode-spritekit-swift/) as well. Also, it could be worth of mentioning that `anchorPoint` is purely visual property and doesn't affect on node's physics body (if defined). Physics body of a node will remain centered by default on node's position if not defined differently (using the `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:` method). Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095389/sprite-kit-change-anchorpoint-but-keep-physicsbody-centered)